# How to run a function without inputting a variable in to the args

Tags: python-3.x, macos

Im using the `cryptography` library and I have generated a key, which I want to pass around the file.  Here is an example:

```
def gen_key():
    password = "password"
    rng = os.urandom(16)
    key_criteria = PBKDF2HMAC(
        algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
        length=32,
        salt=rng,
        iterations=100000,
        backend=default_backend()
    )
    key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(key_criteria.derive(password))
    key = Fernet(key)
    return(key)

def encrypt_str(txt):
    '''
    @param Given string

    generates key, converts str to bytes, then ecrypts

    :return: encrypted str
    '''
    txt = bytes(txt, encoding='utf-8')
    key = key_and_cert_generation.gen_key("password")

    encrypted_text = key.encrypt(txt)
    return(encrypted_text, key)
```

As you can see I generate a key, however when I want to decrypt the text I need the same key and I don't know how I would go about saving the generated key.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you are asking, but it sounds like global variables could help you out. Global variables exist throughout the whole file, instead of just inside your function. You can declare your variable *key* global somewhere in your function like this:

```
global key
```

Hopefully this will help you out!